# Literature on second order finite difference schemes convergence analysis

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, book-recommendation, computational-mathematics, soliton-theory

Okay I am studying Klein-Gordon type equations
$$
\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2} - \Delta u = f(u)
$$
With initial conditions $u(0,\mathbf{x})$, $\dot{u}(0,\mathbf{x})$.
And I have the following finite difference scheme (one dimensional for illustration):
$$
\begin{align}
  v_m^{n+1} &= v_m^n + \left(\frac{u_{m-1}^n - 2 u_m^n + u_{m+1}^n}{h^2}+ f(u_m^n) \right)k, \\
  u_m^{k+1} &= u_m^n + v_m^nk.
\end{align}
$$
I want to ask for **book** or **text** recommendations on how to perform convergence analysis. I have been following Strikwerda's book but I wanted to see if there was a more straightforward treatment when dealing with this kind of schemes.

Comment: Must $f$ be linear as in the case of the Klein-Gordon equation? Or is it allowed to be nonlinear?

Comment: Presumably you can just apply [Von Neumann analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_stability_analysis) ?

Comment: Non-linearity is allowed @K.defaoite